# Build a Query to use a JSON array of values in one table to SELECT rows in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, subquery

I am trying to select rows from one table based on matching a column in that table to a JSON array in another table.

For example:

**reader_templates:  The arrays are a JSON datatype:**

```
id: 1
ckeditor_templates:  ["CK_DX_ABD", "CK_DX_ABD2"]
radreports_templates:  ["0000001", "0000005", "0000045WO", "0000045WC", "0000303"]
reader_id:  0001
```

**report_templates:**

```
id: 1
radreport_id:  0000001
..
id:2
radreport_id:  CK_DX_ABD
```

I want to SELECT * from the rows in the report_templates table where the radreport_id matches a value in the ckeditor_templates JSON array, and then also another query to do the same to match a value in the radreports_templates JSON array.  Seems like there should be a way to do that is simple ?

This query gives me a result like:

```
SELECT REPLACE ((SELECT REPLACE((SELECT ckeditor_templates from reader_templates WHERE reader_id = '0001'), '[', '')),']','')

"CK_DX_ABD", "CK_DX_ABD2"
```

and I was hoping that I could use that with an "WHERE IN" Clause to give me the result that I am looking for, or otherwise use some of the JSON functions to do the same.

Comment: Provide a sample and desired result according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Also specify precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this actually seems to work to generate the matches from the reader_templates tables as rows:

```
SELECT radreport_id FROM reader_templates 
CROSS JOIN json_table(ckeditor_templates, '$[*]' COLUMNS ( 
  radreport_id varchar(20) path '$')) AS temp WHERE reader_id = '0001';
```

Result

```
radreport_id

CK_DX_ABD
CK_DX_ABD2
```

and then I can use that in the "IN" clause as subquery:

```
SELECT * from report_templates WHERE radreport_id IN
(SELECT radreport_id FROM reader_templates 
CROSS JOIN json_table(ckeditor_templates, '$[*]' COLUMNS ( 
  radreport_id varchar(20) path '$')) AS temp WHERE reader_id = '0001')
```

Gives the row matching those radreport_id's, which is what I'm looking for.

Only issue seemed to be that I had to change the encoding for collation for radreport_id from utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8mb4_bin, which is the collation for JSON apparently.

I'll have to play around with it a little more, but that is the result I want.

The query for the other set, radreports_templates, is similar:

```
SELECT * from report_templates WHERE radreport_id IN
(SELECT radreport_id FROM reader_templates 
CROSS JOIN json_table(radreports_templates, '$[*]' COLUMNS ( 
  radreport_id varchar(20) path '$')) AS temp WHERE reader_id = '0001')
```

The scenario is that I have a set of templates in just one table with unique radreport_id's, and there are two different types of templates in that table.  It is actually somewhat easier to have them all in one table, and then to store the ones that a particular user wants to have in their "set", a subset of the total, as JSON in that other table, instead of having a separate row for each choice.  Not sure which is the best way, but this works and seems fast enough.  There will not be many more the 100-200 templates.